# PowerShell to update Excel Power Query (source is MS SQL)

Tags: excel, powershell, powerquery

I have the following PowerShell script that runs successfully for the most part:

**File1.ps1**

```
# Path to the Excel file on SharePoint
$excelFilePath = "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/DocumentCenter/Reports/Analysis/Client/File1.xlsx"

# Create an Excel application object
$excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# Make Excel visible
$excelApp.Visible = $true

# Set Excel to open maximized
$excelApp.WindowState = -4137

# Open the workbook from SharePoint
$workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($excelFilePath)

# Refresh all data connections in the workbook
$workbook.RefreshAll()

# Delay for 7 minutes
Start-Sleep -Seconds 420

# Refresh all pivot tables in the workbook
foreach ($worksheet in $workbook.Worksheets) {
    foreach ($pivotTable in $worksheet.PivotTables()) {
        $pivotTable.RefreshTable()
    }
}

# Delay for 30 seconds
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

# Save the workbook
$workbook.Save()

# Close the workbook without saving changes
$workbook.Close($false)

# Quit Excel application
$excelApp.Quit()

# Release COM objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelApp) | Out-Null
```

My Excel file has 5 Power Queries in the Power Query Editor, each of which extract data from unique MSSQL parameterized stored procedures using different connection strings (more on this information below) and load into hidden Excel sheets which have the same names as the queries themselves. From these hidden sheets I load to Pivot Tables and Pivot Charts and generate various visuals on separate unhidden sheets for consumption.

However a more efficient approach would be to refresh each Power Query in series: when one is finished, identify that the operation is finished and move onto the next one until they are all finished refreshing, instead of hard coding a 7 minute wait for all of them to refresh (which may be prone to ending prematurely depending on how busy the MSSQL server is).

The Power Queries within File1.xlsx are called:

DATA1 (= Sql.Database("10.x.x.x\U_S", "DB", [Query="EXEC StoredProcedure_DATA1 @Param1 = 'Client1'"])

DATA2 (= Sql.Database("10.x.x.x\U_S", "DB", [Query="EXEC StoredProcedure_DATA2 @Param1 = 'Client1'"])

DATA3 (= Sql.Database("10.x.x.x\U_S", "DB", [Query="EXEC StoredProcedure_DATA3 @Param1 = 'Client1'"])

DATA4 (= Sql.Database("10.x.x.x\U_S", "DB", [Query="EXEC StoredProcedure_DATA4 @Param1 = 'Client1'"])

DATA5 (=DATA_3) *this query is duplicated from DATA_3*

What do I need to modify in this PowerShell script to achieve this?

Comment: It's been a long time since I did anything like this but I believe I disabled background refresh on the connections.  Then the application waits for the refresh to complete before moving on.

Comment: Wow , that was simple. It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per Bee_Rii, simply disabling Background Refresh within each query did the trick.